# Отправа сылки на почту для сброса пароля

Tags: python, django, password

Мне нужно реализовать сброс пароля у пользвателя. Я указываю данные от Google почты. У аккаунта нет двойной верификации.
Выдает ошибку:
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c22-20020a05600c0ad600b003fa98908014sm4751656wmr.8 - gsmtp')

Пробовал использовать аккаунт с верификацией, но в итоге выдавала туже ошибку. Использую Django 4.2.3

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = password
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_resset.html'), name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_resset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_resset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),

]
```

Comment: Во-первых, создайте пароль приложения в настройках гуглоаккаунта. Во-вторых, гуглопочта не очень предназначена для автоматических рассылок